# Commerce Payment method with custom fields

Tags: commerce

I am trying to create simple payment method with some text-fields the customer must fill out.

Spend a lot of hours on this and can not figure it out.

Right now I am trying to make a custom PaymentMethodType and ad it to a custom PaymentGateWay but i can not get it to work.

Can not find any documentation on creating PaymentMethodTypes.

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/payments/create-payment-gateway/on-site-gateways/stored-payment-methods) and also the [payment example module](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce/-/tree/8.x-2.x/modules/payment_example)

Comment: The docs only include PaymentMethods not PaymentMethodTypes.
The Examples do not include any custom PaymentMethodTypes.